# ASP.NET Core deployed on IIS gives error: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, windows-7-x64

I've gone through several posts online related to this error but most of these posts are related to classic ASP.NET, and a few that are related to ASP.NET core did not help either.

I created an `ASP.NET Core` app on `VS2017` exactly following this [official ASP.NET tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db). Deployed the app on the IIS on same local machine (`Win 7.0 64bit`) using this [official ASP.NET tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis). But when I browse the app in IIS I get the following **error**:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden.
>   The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

**NOTE**: The app runs fine inside `VS2017` and the IIS in question is on the same machine as on `VS2017`. I've verified the path is correct. All the requirements for IIS deployment mentioned in the above tutorial are satisfied.

Comment: Please show us the URL you are trying to load. And what you expect that URL to return.

Comment: @mjwills Your question actually resolved my issue (thank you). I was pointing to a **wrong folder**. Folder structure is `C:\MVC_IIS\Blogs\PublishOutput_Blogs` where `PublishOutput_Blogs` is the folder where I have published the app. But my mistake, instead of pointing the physical path in IIS to `PublishOutput_Blogs`  I was pointing it to `\MVC_IIS\Blogs`. If you like you can write a response and I'll mark it as an answer since you actually helped me find my own mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest verifying that your IIS is pointed to the correct folder.

Pointing it to an incorrect folder could explain what you are seeing.